# Generate table in success ajax MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need generate table in success ajax and draw in html. But I dont know how can I fill my table. I try this, but nothing draw.

```
$.ajax({
url: '/Private/Index',
method: 'POST',
dataType: "json",
data: $(addNewEduForm).serialize() + '&' + $.param(mm),
traditional: true,
success: function (selected) {
    $('#your-modal').modal('toggle');
    var row = $('<tr>');
    for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
        row.append($('<td>').html(selected[i]));
    }
    $('#results').append(row);
},
error: function (error) {

}
});
```

My  console.log(selected) :
[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/813fN.png)
And my html, where I need draw the table:

```
<table class="table_blur">
<tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Event</th>
    <th>First</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

As result I need :

```
<th>Date</th><th>Event</th><th>FirstTeam</th>
<DateFromSelected><EventFrom Selected><FirstTeam>
```

Comment: so, in order to answer your question, you should show us how your ajax response looks like.. in your success function, console.log(selected); edit your question with a sample ajax response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need that your code looks like that, for example you need show `DateofEvent` and `FirstTeam`.

**HTML CODE**

```
<table id="results">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>DateofEvent</td>
        <td>FirstTeam</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tboby>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**JS CODE**

```
$.ajax({
url: '/Private/Index',
method: 'POST',
dataType: "json",
data: $(addNewEduForm).serialize() + '&' + $.param(mm),
traditional: true,
success: function (selected) {
    $('#your-modal').modal('toggle');
    var row = $('<tr>');
    for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
        row.append($('<td>').html(selected[i].DateofEvent));
        row.append($('<td>').html(selected[i].FirstTeam));
    }
    $('#results').append(row);
},
error: function (error) {

}
});
```

*remember that you return a collection of objects and you access them by name.